# STL vector usage problem -- Function returning non-zero Iterator

Tags: c++

I was trying to use the vector STL, where iam facing a weird response from the following sample program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int>::iterator  fun();
  vector<int> myvector;

bool IsOdd (int i) {
  return ((i%2)==1);
}

int main()
{
   vector<int>::iterator  it;

     it = fun();

if (it == myvector.end() )
cout << "Reached end, Global" << endl;
else
cout << "Not end" << endl;


}

vector<int>::iterator  fun() {
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  myvector.push_back(10);
  myvector.push_back(26);
  myvector.push_back(40);
  myvector.push_back(56);

  it = find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
  cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << endl;

if (it == myvector.end() )
cout << "Reached end, inside the function" << endl;
else
cout << "Not end" << endl;

  return it;
}
```

Iam getting "Reached End" inside the function fun(), whereas, in the main program, it is showing up as "Not End".

Not sure, what might be the reason. Also, found that, the Address of myvector.end() is showing up as Zero in the main program [ after the fun() call ], where-as, showing a non-zero value inside the function fun().

Comment: @Roopesh: it's better if you don't edit the code to fix the problem you're asking about - the question will no longer makes sense. Or do you still get the same problem after that change?

Comment: I've run corrected code - it logs "Reached end" both in main and in fun...

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to remove it [ the local instance of "myvector"  ] ... Even if i remove the local instance of myvector, it is showing up the reported problem.

Comment: This code will most probably crash as the in `std::cout` you are trying to dereference an invalid iterator (There is no odd value in the vector). Show us the *real code* with which the problem is reproducible. Copy paste directly from your editor.

Comment: Yes Mike, the problem is still occuring in my code, even after removing the local instance of the variable. However, if i try in a sample program, it is working fine. But when tried in my real time application, it is ending up with this error.

Comment: Then you should provide more details from your real program as a sample one works fine...

Comment: Guys, I was able to resolve the problem. The reason it is failing, in my real time application, is that... I was sending the whole vector to the function, where it is being taken as a local copy. That was the reason for 2 different results.

Thanks all, who helped me, to sort out the problem.

Comment: Changing the text of the question substantially after people have started reading can only lead to confusion...

Answer (score 2):

The function is using the local myvector, main is using the global one.

Your modified code produces:

```
Reached end, inside the function
Reached end, Global
```

as expected.

**Edit:** Well, not as expected - as others have pointed out:

```
it = find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << endl;
```

will cause undefined behaviour with your dataset, because you  don't have any odd values. You want:

```
it = find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
if ( it != myvector.end() ) {
  cout << "The first odd value is " << *it << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `myvector`s, one is global, another is in `fun`. Therefore, you're comparing an iterator to the global vector with an iterator to a local vector which moreover doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of `vector` with name `myvector`. One global and one local to function `fun`. Inside `fun` this local vector hides the global vector. Since you are operating on two totally different vector objects you are seeing these results.

Answer (score 0):

You dereferenced *it without checking if it was before the end. None of your vector values are odd, so it will be end and you will cause undefined behaviour by dereferencing it.